# How to check if string is valid by checking if its value is in array

Tags: joi, hapi

`joi.string().valid(['foo', 'bar'])` has been deprecated.

> Error: Method no longer accepts array arguments: allow

What is the new way of achieving this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) works perfectly!

```
joi.string().valid(...['foo', 'bar'])
```